# Not Quite A Series: Perturbing a Geometric Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\alpha\in\mathbb{R} : 0<\alpha<1$. Then, the sequence
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (-\alpha)^k
$$
converges to zero (apply binomial theorem). What about the following? Say, $(x_n)$ is a bounded sequence of complex numbers, and we take
$$
a_n := \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (-\alpha)^k x_k.
$$
Under what circumstances, if any, can we conclude that 
$$
|a_n| \leq |\Omega_1 (1-\alpha)^n + \Omega_2|
$$ 
for some $\Omega_1,\Omega_2$, for all but finitely many $n$? Under what circumstances can we expect convergence? Any thoughts? Thanks.

Edit: Perhaps it is better to ask, what is the best (i.e., weakest) sufficient condition we can come up with for having $a_n$ converge? For have $
|a_n| \leq |\Omega_1 (1-\alpha)^n + \Omega_2|
$ for large $n$?
I ask because most common theorems (e.g., theorems about series) don't apply.

Comment: "if any"? you already said $x_k = 1$ for all $k$ works

Comment: if you take $x_k=(-1)^k$ then $a_n=(1+\alpha)^n$ so blows up quickly; similarly if you take $x_k=3, k=2n$, $x_k=1, k=2n+1$ because then you get $a_n=(1+\alpha)^n+2(1-\alpha)^n$ and that also blows up fast, so things are tricky

Comment: @mathworker - sorry, many times comments appear weird as I cannot see them when I type, so have to edit - coming back to this type of problem, taking convergent series that are alternating and not absolutely convergent and weighing each term in them even with positive multipliers destroys convergence in general as for example here, so this is a very tricky question in general

Comment: Ok, that's fair. @Conrad don't worry about the commenting twice, it's welcome. Yeah, I guess, if $(x_k)$ is constant then this works. But this is a over-power sufficient condition I would think. Is there a more general setting in which we can conclude the desired results? Certainly, $(x_n)$ being constant is not *necessary.*

Comment: @Conrad i don't understand why you end up with "so this is a very tricky question in general". first of all, i dont even know what "in general means". thomas asked for sufficient condiitons for convergent, which probably can be provided in some generality. for example, if $x_n$ is non-negative and monotone, idk.

Comment: Yeah, so this is related to a passion project I'm working on. I mean, I personally think this is hard. Imagine that $(x_n)$ is arbitrarily given, and suppose that it is an unreasonably strong assumption that $(x_n)$ is constant (there really wouldn't be much question in that case). Alternating series test does not apply, I believe, since it's not quite a series. For example, the term $\binom{n}{k}$ changes not only with the index of summation $k$, but also with $n$. So we have a sequence of the form $\sum_{k=0}^n a_{k,n}$, not of the form $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k$.

Comment: @math actually this type of problem interests me in a different setting and I am not sure your example works here unless $x_n$ decreases fast (assuming $x_n$ is non-constant of course)

Comment: That, we might not have, although I'd still be interested in hearing more. It's weird. If you have $M>|x_k|$ for all $k$ and $x_k$ is not *constant* but is fairly consistent (e.g., we *don't* have something like $x_k = 0$ for all odd $k$), then intuitively I would think the summation gets trapped (because it alternates) within a disk, although that is just speculation, and obviously it's not that simple.

Comment: @math $x_k =\frac{1}{k}$ blows the sum away quite fast for say $\alpha =.99$ (check for $n=100$ with Wolfram Alpha for fun) and is decreasing and non negative - you need something like $x_k=c+f(k)$ where  $f$ decreasing fast enough depending on $\alpha$ - looking at the shape of the largest binomial coefficient for say even $n$ should give you some ideas in this case

Comment: You know, in the context of what I'm working on (which I have not provided, only because it's a lot of context), having $x_k = c + f(k)$ might be achievable. I'd be interested in hearing more. Is there any known body of theory on problems like this? I'm not very familiar with the literature.

Comment: Would this $f(k)$ need to decrease faster than a factorial increases? Or would it be enough to have something like $f(k) = \varepsilon^k$ for a very small $\varepsilon$?

Comment: the only thing that comes to mind is partial summation (the sums I tend to look at that are of the type $\sum {a_k}$ much much smaller (in various definite quantitative ways) than $\sum{|a_k|}$ are in the exponential sums area and I am not sure that specific techniques from there apply here except for partial summation on the binomial coefficients, so you need to understand $\binom{n}{k}-\binom{n}{k-1}$; $\epsilon ^k$ gets absorbed into $\alpha^k$, so it should work as long as $\epsilon \alpha <1$ -

Comment: There is a partial summation formula (Thm 3.41 in baby Rudin) which leads to $a_n = x_n(1-\alpha)^n + \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \left( \sum\limits_{\ell=0}^k \dbinom{n}{\ell} (-\alpha)^\ell \right) (x_k - x_{k+1})$, but I'm not sure that this helps, and it starts to look like a "rabit hole." Should I add this to the statement of the question maybe?

Comment: as noted $\epsilon^k$ definitely works as it gets absorbed into $(-\alpha)^k$, so that's one good perturbation if it helps you

Comment: Yeah, I was just gonna say that is a very good point. I didn't think of that. Now I will take a minute to think about that if achievable in the setting of my project... You might have actually just solved my problem

Comment: Not exactly... but I think I can achieve something similar. I'll double check tomorrow (if it is still correct after sleeping on it then we're good), and I can provide more details if this is of interest. If not, just know that this quick online discussion has been potentially very helpful for me. I'm grateful.